# Is there a way to generate a new variable only if it meets certain criteria?

Tags: if-statement, select, filter, dplyr, case-when

I am trying to replicate the following Stata code in R:

```
gen UAPDL_1=sqrt((((Sanchez_1-Iglesias_1)^2)+((Casado_1-Iglesias_1)^2)+((Rivera_1-Iglesias_1)^2))/3) if maxIglesias_1==1

replace UAPDL_1=sqrt((((Sanchez_1-Rivera_1)^2)+((Casado_1-Rivera_1)^2)+((Iglesias_1-Rivera_1)^2))/3) if maxRivera_1==1
```

In other words, I am trying to make different calculations and generate a new variable with different values depending on certain conditions (in this case, they have value 1 in an another variable. I managed to create the variables to be met for making the calculation (maxIglesias==1 and maxRivera==1), but I am stuck in the generation of the UAPDL variable. I tried with `case_when` and `ifelse`, but in these cases these commands only let you define a certain value. Is there a way with mutate or dplyr (or any other package) to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Let me try to 'parse' your question for the sake of clarity.

You want to generate a variable UAPDL depending on the value of two distinct variables (maxIglesias_1 and maxRivera_1, which let's say correspond to values f(I) and f(R), respectively). Here I note that, according to the snippet of the code you posted, there is no guarantee that the two variables are mutually exclusive - i.e., you may have records with maxIglesias_1 == 1 AND maxRivera_1 == 1. In those cases, the order in which you run the commands matters, as they all end up valued f(R), or f(I) if you twist them.

However, in order to replicate the Stata commands that you posted (issue with the ordering included!) you should run

```
UAPDL_1 <- numeric(length(maxIglesias_1)) # generate the vector
UAPDL_1[maxIglesias_1 == 1] <- f(I)
UAPDL_1[maxRivera_1 == 1] <- f(R)
```

where I assume that `maxIglesias_1` and `maxIglesias_1` are two R objects of the same length as the original Stata matrix.

Good luck!